# Is $T(T^2)^{-1}$ a left-inverse for $T$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, functional-calculus

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T:\text{dom}(T)\rightarrow H$ be a densely defined, closed self-adjoint operator. Suppose that $T^2: \text{dom}(T^2)\rightarrow H$ has a bounded inverse $(T^2)^{-1}:H\rightarrow \text{dom}(T^2)$.

Here $\text{dom}(T^2):=\{u\in\text{dom}(T):Tu\in\text{dom}(T)\}$.

**Question:** Can one conclude that $T$ is invertible? That is, does there exist a bounded operator $T^{-1}:H\rightarrow\text{dom}(T)$ that is a two-sided inverse of $T$?

The natural thing to do seems to be to construct $T^{-1}$ from $(T^2)^{-1}$, and indeed a right-inverse for $T$ is $T(T^2)^{-1}$. But it is not clear to me how show it is also a left-inverse, as some commutativity seems required (and even if they "did" the domains would not make sense). Perhaps one can use the functional calculus of self-adjoint operators to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \in \operatorname{dom}(T)$, we have

\begin{align}
T(T^2)^{-1}Tx &= T(T^2)^{-1}T \operatorname{id}_H x \\
&= T(T^2)^{-1}TT^2(T^2)^{-1}x \\
&= T(T^2)^{-1}T^2T(T^2)^{-1}x \tag{1}\\
&= TT(T^2)^{-1}x \tag{2}\\
&= x,
\end{align}
where dropping the $(T^2)^{-1}T^2$ in the step from $(1)$ to $(2)$ is valid because $T(T^2)^{-1}x \in \operatorname{dom}(T^2)$ for $x \in \operatorname{dom}(T)$.

Thus $T(T^2)^{-1}$ is indeed a left inverse of $T$, as well as a right inverse. Furthermore, it is a globally defined closed operator, hence continuous.

Comment: Is $T(T^2)^{-1}$ closed because it is the composition $TI(T^2)^{-1}$ of bounded and closed operators (where $I:\text{dom}(T^2)\hookrightarrow\text{dom}(T)$ is the inclusion)?

Comment: Yes, but view $T$ as an operator on $H$. If $A$ is a closed operator, and $B$ continuous, then $A\circ B$ is closed: suppose we have a sequence $x_n \to x$ such that $A(B x_n) \to y$. By continuity of $B$, we have $B x_n \to Bx$, and thus by closedness of $A$ we have $Bx \in \operatorname{dom}(A)$ - but that means just $x \in \operatorname{dom}(AB)$ - and $A(Bx) = y$.